# How to display posts in order of ACF field values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have posts sorted by different parameters. Each post has an ACF select field top_rated. There is also sorting by Top Rated parameter - this is a separate parameter in the admin panel for each post. The ACF top_rated field can have 3 values: Number_1
Number_2
Number_3

I need to make sure that if the sorting is by Top Rated, then the first three posts are displayed those with the ACF value of the field top_rated Number_1
Number_2
Number_3 and only then all the rest. Now my code displays only the post with Number_1, but I need the first three posts with Number_1
Number_2
Number_3 and then all the rest. How to do it?

```js
static function load_brokers_by_category($array_filter)
{

    $tax_query = [];
    if (!empty($array_filter)) {
        $tax_query = [
            'relation' => 'AND'
        ];
        $all_taxonomy = get_object_taxonomies(['brokers']);
        foreach ($array_filter as $taxonomy => $tax_item) {
            if (in_array($taxonomy, $all_taxonomy)) {
                if (is_array($tax_item)) {
                    foreach ($tax_item as $t_i) {
                        if (!empty($t_i)) {
                            $t_a[] = [
                                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                                'field' => 'slug',
                                'terms' => explode(',', $t_i)
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                    if (!empty($t_a)) {
                        $tax_query[] = array_merge(['relation' => 'OR'], $t_a);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!empty($tax_item)) {
                        $tax_query[] = [
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => explode(',', $tax_item)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $sort_by = isset($_GET['sort_by']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['sort_by']) : (isset($_POST['sort_by']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['sort_by']) : 'post_date');

    $wp_query_array = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'brokers',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        'order' => ($sort_by === 'post_date') || ($sort_by === 'top_rated') ? 'DESC' : (($sort_by === 'title') || ($sort_by === 'low_rated') ? 'ASC' : 'meta_value_num'),
        'orderby' => ($sort_by === 'post_date') ? 'post_date' : (($sort_by === 'title') ? 'title' : 'meta_value_num'),
        'meta_key' => 'rating'
    ];

    if ($sort_by === 'top_rated') {
        $wp_query_array['meta_query'] = [
            'relation' => 'AND',
            [
                'key' => 'top_rated',
                'value' => 'Number_1',
                'compare' => '=',
            ],
        ];
    }

    $query_brokers = new WP_Query($wp_query_array);

    return $query_brokers;
}
```